# VBScript WScript.Shell Run() - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to write a VBScript (.vbs) script that uses the WScript.Shell **Run()** method, but it seems as though Run() can't find the file I'm passing in.

I've boiled my script down to the following code that will reproduce the results. This can be copied to a text editor, saved as *test.vbs* and ran. *The **type** command simply outputs the text inside the file passed in.*

```
Dim WShell
Set WShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WShell.Run("type C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm")

Set WShell = Nothing
```

If you were to run the code in Run() directly from the CMD prompt, it works fine. But when it's run from inside a .vbs script and using Run(), it gives me the following error:

```
Test.vbs(4, 1) (null): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can run other commands using Run() just fine, but when I try to pass in a path it fails. Exec() fails with the same error by the way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strCmd = "cmd /K type C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm"

oShell.Run(strCmd)

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Use of `cmd.exe .k` is necessary because `TYPE` isn't an actual executable program but rather an internal command within the CMD Command Processor.